# Uncaught syntax error: unexpected token < error

Tags: vuejs2, service-worker, webpack-4, workbox-webpack-plugin

I'm using service worker and caching with workbox using webpack for a `vuejs` app. While it worked fine until now, when I pushed new changes to our app, the app breaks after reloading the page and gives this error. Also, in the network tab, I see that it is requesting a non-existing app.js build file which was a previous deploy file. How do I solve this?

If you observe the image, you can see that the request is going to older app.js file while in the dist folder to the left, the hash of app.js bundled is different.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9NwV.png)

Comment: You should include more details on your issue. We have little clue of what is going on. Copy past the error and you code you are using.

Comment: Could you please check the image now.